# Legendre's formula for the surface area of scalene ellipsoid

Tags: area, elliptic-integrals, ellipsoids

I am looking for a derivation of the formula
$$S=2\pi c^2 +\frac{2\pi a b}{\sin \varphi}\left(E(\varphi, k)\sin ^2 \varphi +F(\varphi,k)\cos^2 \varphi\right)$$
for the surface area of the ellipsoid
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$
with $$a>b>c, \hspace{3ex} \cos \varphi=\frac{c}{a}, \hspace{3ex} k^2=\frac{a^2(b^2-c^2)}{b^2(a^2-c^2)},$$
where $F(\varphi,k)$ is Legendre's incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind and $E(\varphi,k)$ is Legendre's incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind. This formula is simpler (and more elegant) than what one gets by integrating
$$\int_0^a \int_0^{b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2}dydx.$$ The formula was derived in a long and complicated way in an 1825 paper by Legendre, and it is often quoted (see for example the Wikipedia entry for ellipsoid), but I cannot find a proof.

Comment: See Maas' paper [*here*](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~maas0131/files/MaasJCAM1994.pdf).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497316/an-integral-identity-about-the-elliptic-integrals-and-ellipsoids