# An integral Identity about the Elliptic Integrals and Ellipsoids

Tags: elliptic-integrals, ellipsoids

I was reading this article: [https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~maas0131/files/MaasJCAM1994.pdf](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Emaas0131/files/MaasJCAM1994.pdf)

I came to the equation (24):

The author says... "We thus find, by the same argument,":

$$\int_0^1 f(\xi)E(k\sqrt{1-\xi^2})d\xi=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-k^2\xi^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sqrt{1-\xi^2}cos\phi)d\phi d\xi$$

I can not prove it. Can you help me?

I am also stack in a line of the same article. He wrote (below the equation (49)):
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1+\rho\cos^2\phi)^2}d\phi=\frac{1}{4}\pi\frac{2+\rho}{(1+\rho)^{3/2}}$$
How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, what we want to show is that
$$
\int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^{\pi/2}f(\xi)\sqrt{1-k^2(1-\xi^2)\sin^2\phi} d\phi d\xi = \int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^{\pi/2}f\left(\sqrt{1-u^2}\cos\theta\right)\sqrt{1-k u^2}d\theta du,
$$
where I have renamed the dummy variables in the second integral to reduce ambiguity. It turns out the direct change of variables
$$
\xi \rightarrow \sqrt{1-u^2}\cos\theta\,\,\,,\,\,\,\sqrt{1-\xi^2}\sin\phi \rightarrow u.
$$
has a Jacobian of $1$. To see this, first show that $\sqrt{1-\xi^2}\cos\phi d\phi d\xi = \sqrt{1-u^2}\sin\theta d \theta d u$ by differentiating both sides of the change of variable equations. Then we use
$$
(1-\xi^2)\cos\phi^2 = (1-\xi^2) - (1-\xi^2)\sin^2\phi = 1-(1-u^2)\cos^2\theta - u^2 = (1-u^2)\sin^2\theta.
$$
to show that in fact $d\phi d\xi =d\theta du$, and the identity follows.

Comment: Very difficult. Have you done this yourself? Second assignment is mind blowing.

Comment: @MehmetKırdar The shared limits of integration once you expand the elliptic integral strongly suggest a substitution like this. As for the Jacobian, I started from the conclusion the identity was true and worked backwards to how it followed from the change of variables.

Comment: It is possible to get a direct substitution $\phi=\phi(u,\theta)$. But then Jacobian calculation is very complicated.

Comment: @MehmetKırdar A geometric interpretation of the identity is given in the linked article. Let $\omega = 1/\sqrt {1 - k^2}$. Take $\mathcal S$ to be the part of the ellipsoid $x^2 + (y/\omega)^2 + z^2 = 1$ lying in the $(+, +, +)$ octant. Evaluate $\int_{\mathcal S} f(z) \, dS$ by parametrizing $\mathcal S$ as
$$(x, y, z) =
(\sqrt {\smash [b] {1 - \xi^2}} \cos \phi,
 \omega \sqrt {\smash [b] {1 - \xi^2}} \sin \phi,
 \xi)$$
and as
$$(x, y, z) =
(\sqrt {\smash [b] {1 - \xi^2}} \sin \phi,
 \omega \xi,
 \sqrt {\smash [b] {1 - \xi^2}} \cos \phi).$$
You'll get the desired identity.

Comment: @MehmetKırdar It's worth noting that when deriving these identities, either through my or Maxim's method, it's probably more intuitive if you use $\xi = \sin\psi$ (and in my method, $u = \sin\chi$). The reason is that the $\sqrt{1-\xi^2}$ becomes $\cos\psi$ (and similarly for $u$), which both makes things cleaner and lets the underlying trig be more apparent.